# Angular directives fetching template via URL throwing exceptions in Play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I've ported an application to Play v2.3.1.  Our front-end is running under Angular.  In many of our directives, I'll define a separate, static HTML file which I'm storing in /public/angular/...  Up unto this point it has worked fine, but after upgrading Play, I've begun getting the same exception repeated for each template that is fetched.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "0"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873) ~[joda-time-2.3.jar:2.3]
    at controllers.AssetInfo$.parseDate(Assets.scala:91) ~[play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$controllers$AssetsBuilder$$maybeNotModified$3.apply(Assets.scala:319) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$controllers$AssetsBuilder$$maybeNotModified$3.apply(Assets.scala:318) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder.controllers$AssetsBuilder$$maybeNotModified(Assets.scala:318) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Assets.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Assets.scala:397) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Assets.scala:397) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Assets.scala:394) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46) [play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$DefaultPromise$$dispatchOrAddCallback(Promise.scala:280) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.onComplete(Promise.scala:270) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$class.flatMap(Future.scala:249) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.flatMap(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1.apply(Assets.scala:393) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1.apply(Assets.scala:389) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:556) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:555) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:518) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121) [play_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:705) [play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:705) [play-iteratees_2.10-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library.jar:na]
```

It's strange because the exception is thrown but everything else operates as normal.  From within the directives, I'm specifying the templateUrl parameter as follows:

```
templateUrl: '/assets/angular/<path to actual resource>'
```

In the routes file I've got:

```
GET    /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the new way in which Assets are being handled, but as far as I can tell, this should (and does -- but with an exception) work fine.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm guessing that it is something with how angular formats the 'If-Modified-Since' header in the request.

Comment: @johanandren I think you're on to something there.  The template fetches do in fact have that header information inserted with the value simply as '0'.  (All the others have a valid date.)  Do you have a suggestion for fixing this?

Comment: @johanandren -- If you create an answer then I'll approve it. -- Ok, I realized that I am causing this problem.  In order to avoid another problem with IE, I am intercepting GET requests and adding the 'If-Modified-Since' field with a value of 0.  Changing it to a valid date in the past (e.g. Thu, 02 Feb 1984 05:00:00 GMT) solved the problem.